# Can you work out page size in physical memory without knowing the number of pages?

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory

Suppose physical memory is split into physical pages (aka page frames), which have equal size. Suppose we know that on our system, the number of page frames in the physical memory equals the number of bytes in a page frame. We also know that physical addresses have 26 bits. How many bytes are in a page frame?

I'm really struggling with this question and I would be glad for any pointers on how to work this out.

Thanks!

I have tried working out the size of the address space (2^26) but that didn't really work.

Comment: Sounds like they're looking for `2^26 =  2^13 * 2^13`

Comment: So that's 2^13 bits (1024 bytes) and 2^13 page frames?